# Super noob requesting help testing dice balance

Tags: statistical-significance, bias, dice

So, I have a few sets of polyhedral dice (77 individual dice) that I'd like to try to test for balance. I'm thinking a decent sample size is to roll each of them 100 times, then plot the proportional occurrence of each resulting number, and test that proportion against the neutral expected percentage (ie 1/4,1/6,1/8,1/10,1/12,1/20) and determine the statistical significance to test for bias.

The problem is that it's been so long since I've done this stuff. I took statistics nearly 10 years ago and while I used to know all the formulae and jargon, now I can remember almost nothing other than a general understanding of the terms.

I've read a couple of similar questions on here, but the answers are all so technical I cant begin to recall how to do any of it. So, I'm essentially at the mercy of a kind-hearted soul who can help me through the process.

I still have SPSS from my college days but I'm happy to get a different software too.

Is there anybody generous enough to help a hopelessly rusty noob with this endeavour?

Sincere thanks,

Frank

Comment: Something not shown at link. 6-sided die is unfair with 4,5,6 twice as likely as 1,2,3. Roll 100 times in R. Chi-squared test rejects 'fairness' with tiny P-value.
`set.seed(2022);
x = sample(1:6,100, rep=T, p = c(1,1,1,2,2,2));
t =tabulate(x); t` returns
`[1]  3 17  8 30 19 23` Then
`chisq.test(t)$p.val` returns
`[1] 2.196391e-05`.`